# How to submit a form in a UIWebView loaded with HTMLString:baseURL:?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, forms, uiwebview

oHi,

I'm displaying a html page which contains a form with some input text fields and a submit button.

- If i display the page using *loadRequest:* everything works fine.
- If i display the same page using *loadHTMLString:baseURL:* the submit button is not working anymore.

The adress which is supposed to be called is :

http://..../lire.php?id=33570#bloc_commentaire

If i log the adress it tries to reach i got :

> applewebdata://BF6F3D92-9F36-40CA-A3EB-BCD3F14852B6#bloc_commentaire

**Do you have any idea of what i should do to be able to post a form loaded statically using loadHTMLString:baseURL: ?**

Thanks,
Vincent

Comment: what baseURL are you specifying?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem occurs because your web view doesn't know where to post the data because the html is loaded from a string and not a specific web server.

Make sure you are setting `baseURL` correctly in your call to

```
 [webView loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL]
```

**Details:**

When the webview finds a relative url in the html, it joins it with the baseURL to form an absolute url which can be used to submit or click on. For instance:

Given `http://www.test.com/foo/` as `baseURL` and a relative url tag lke `<a href="bar/hello.php">click me</a>`

When the user clicks on the link, the view will make a request to `http://www.test.com/foo/bar/hello.php`

Comment: Thanks that was the problem, the fact is this baseUrl is not really explained in the UIWebView reference, and i never really understood it, could you please briefly explain what it is ?

Comment: @vdaybry: Lets say a browser loads HTML with a <form> from an URL such as http://www.foo.com/test.html. When the user submits that form, the browser will send the form data fields to the server where it loaded the html (http://www.foo.com) and that is the baseURL. In your case, you load the html from a string, so the browser doesn't know *where* it came from and thus cannot know where to send it. The same applies to <img> tags as well. You get the same problem when loading a plain html from your hard drive. Also see the [<base>](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp) tag.

Comment: So, what i should use as baseURL if i load simple html from string